# apktool decompile, rebuild, rename, sign - App not installed

Tags: apktool

I have this problem with apktool.

what I do:

```
apktool d [anyapp from Apkpure].apk
apktool b app
cd ./app/dist
mv app.apk package_name.apk (from AndroidManifest (package attribute))
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty3oW.jpg)

I tried different apktool version (including the last one - 2.7) different jdk - 8,11, different apps. Always the same error. What's wrong?